# How to get state variable value from the URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

My state look like this.

```
$stateProvider.state("user.admin", {
    url: "/administration/:action",
        views:{
            content:{
                templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
                controller: 'AdminController'
            }
        }
    }
);
```

My one of the action is overview. The url looks like this.

```
/administration/overview
```

Is there a way to fetch the action value from the Controller(in this case its overview)? If yes, how?

I would really appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to inject [`$stateParams service`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service) in your controller and grab `action` as its property.

Example:-

```
.controller('AdminController', 
         ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$log', 
 function($scope, $stateParams, $log){

     $log.debug('action', $stateParams.action );

 }])
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

use `$stateParams` to get the state variables.

In this case its

```
$stateParams.action
```